# Is there a semantic difference between the nouns "pack", " pac", and "pak"?

Tags: meaning, slang, semantics, neologisms

The other day when loading the dishwasher with one of those all-in-one, plastic-wrapped detergent balls, I noticed that the individual balls were referred to as "pacs". I've also seen "packs" and "paks" of items, and that got me thinking about similar words.

There's a difference between a disc and a disk, a block and a bloc, and a sack and a sac...

Is there a semantic difference between packs, pacs, and paks? Or is it just the result of creative liberties in the marketing department when labeling consumer goods?

Note: I know there is an acronym "PAC" (political action committee) but I'm talking about the noun pack as in "something containing multiple individual items"

Comment: I'd say that "creative liberties in the marketing department when labeling consumer goods" pretty much nails it.  Consider also Chick-fil-A, Cheez Whiz, Froot Loops, Toys R Us, ....

Comment: As a reminder, you should demonstrate your research, for example, checking to see if *pac* or *pak* are accepted variants of *pack* in a dictionary. They are not.

Comment: @choster Unless one of them refers to a Man of some sort.

Comment: Of course there was a Ms. Pac-Man, too.  And "PAC" is a fairly well known acronym.  And [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pak) lists a score of entries for "Pak" (although most of them are names).

Comment: Probably less "the result of creative liberties in the marketing department when labeling consumer goods" and more the result of globalism and so many goods being made overseas spawning bad English in  labeling consumer goods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The only correct spelling of the word is 'pack'.** Everything else is, as you put it 'creative marketing', i.e. a deliberate misspelling to try to distinguish the product from similar ones or fit in with the cool kids.

As you noted a PAC is an American political committee, and a PAK is a kind of German anti-tank gun, but neither are legitimate alternatives to *pack*.

Disk and disc are identical (but once were associated with US versus British English). Bloc means something different from block, as does sac from sack. A dictionary will give you the details.

Comment: Well, in computing, my understanding is that a *disk* typically is a magnetic medium like a hard disk or a floppy disk, while a *disc* is an optical medium like a CD or a DVD.

Comment: I don't think that is a generally accepted difference.

Comment: Some sources: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/disk#Usage_notes, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disc, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spelling_of_disc